# #1005 - Can't create table TABLE NAME' (errno: 150) (Details…)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have deleted the user table and now wanted to impotieren another user table of the same forensoftware.

But it does not work

I Add SQL Backup Table

https://pastebin.com/uZjbUFEk

This Error Comming on PHPmyAdmin

```
CREATE TABLE `wcf1_user` (
  `userID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `password` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `accessToken` char(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `languageID` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `registrationDate` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `styleID` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `banned` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `banReason` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `banExpires` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `activationCode` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `lastLostPasswordRequestTime` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `lostPasswordKey` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `lastUsernameChange`[...]


 #1005 - Can't create table 'censored.wcf1_user' (errno: 150) (Details…)
```

Comment: This is just a guess rather than an answer, but the `accessToken` column has type `char(40)` while its default value has length 0. Try changing the type to `varchar` or making the default length 40.

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer, just where should i change you in the sql file?

Comment: The problem is not a default of `''` for a character column.  Exclusing the last line, the code works fine:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b91f1.  Error number 150 is a foreign key reference, and you have not shown any such definitions in your question.

Comment: Thx, Only how and where do I enter the foreign key?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/uZjbUFEk

Comment: when I'm at the top of the backup

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;


Enter the same error message